# facebook like button href vs og:url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I would like to clarify one thing.

I have a web page with a facebook like button.

In the head of the page, let's say www.exaple.com, I have

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.example.com">
```

and no canonical link.

In the facebook like box I have

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com?strip=1" data-layout="box_count" data-share="false" data-action="like"></div>
```

The page www.example.com?strip=1 is slightly differentent from www.example.com.

I would expect that when I use the like button, in facebook I will find a post that points to www.example.com?strip=1, but this doesn't happen as I'm redirected to www.example.com.

Can you explain me why this happen? My guess is that Facebook goes to www.example.com?strip=1 and looks for og:url there. Since the og:url in www.example.com/strip=1 is www.example.com I am redirected to www.example.com.

Can you confirm that? Do you have any suggestion on how to keep the og:url as it is but make the like button redirect to www.example.com/strip=1?

For completeness, in the facebook debugger, feeding it with www.example.com/strip=1, it gives me www.example.com?strip=1 as fetched URL and www.example.com as canonical URL.